# Angular Optimization: How APP_INITIALIZER can read response from HTTP Request made outside of it

Tags: angular

I am trying to do performance optimization in Angular site and making a call HTTP Request as part of Index.html to fetch data in parallel to Angular Javascript application being loaded.

I am setting the value 'window.appData' once the HTTP Request is completed.

I would like to make APP_INITIALIZER to wait until window.appData is set before returning the promise. Ideally, I would like to keep polling every 100 millisecond to test for window.appData != null and once it is set return true for remaining application to be loaded.

Sometimes this works; if HTTP Request is complete; but in case http request is not complete. I would like APP_Initializer to keep polling til it's  completed.

Any help or recommendations would be helpful.

```
// Code in Index.html 

fetch(window.config.apiUrl + '/api/v1/resource/GetData')
           .then(function(response) {
             return response.json();
           })
           .then(function(myJson) {
             window.myData = myJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some shared storage like `local storage` and wait to be filled with data.

However, it is very risky what you want to do and you should consider it twice before implementation. This kind of architecture leads to many bizarre errors in future. Those can be difficult to find and fix.

Some possible problems:

1. What if your data request fails? Angular cannot start?
2. Synchronization (Angular / none-Angular part)
3. In the future your Angular app can do many more things. You will prevent entire app working by one data request (by waiting in app initializer)
4. What user can think looking in blank page? Is something happen or page is broken? How much it takes to load?

The key questions you should consider are:

1. How big / long is the request? Is it worth to optimize in this manner? How it takes? 100 ms, 200? How much data weight?
2. Do you need data in APP_INITIALIZER or want to use it only in synchronization purposes?
3. All the app needs those data or some component only?

I encourage you back to the drawing board.

**As far as you don't have exceptional situation, you should load the Angular application and then get data displaying a spinner or splash screen for the user.**

In this case you have full controll for i.e. request fails and loader is friendly for the user.

If you have some exceptional situation, please describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Walter for your response. I do know the implications of it; but I would expect the API to complete the request before the Angular Application is loaded in 90% of the cases; I went with below implementation.

```
initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const siteSettings = window.siteSettings;
        if (siteSettings !== null) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          const subscription = interval(25).subscribe(() => {
            const siteSettings2 = window.siteSettings;
            if (siteSettings2 !== null) {
              subscription.unsubscribe();
              resolve();
            } else {
              // If wait exceeds threshold; fall back to the default flow and load 
              // using angular ajax call 
            }
          });
        }
      }, 0);
    });
  }
```